# Removing text from the middle of a string when fixing a tslint rule

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm trying to create a tslint rule that will prevent our testers to submit a fixture / test that includes `.only`.

So if they try to commit a file that includes `fixture.only` or `test.only` the commit will fail (I'm using Husky + git hooks for doing the tslint command when committing).

I figured out how to create the rule (meaning the commit fails) but it would be nice to also remove this code (fixing the commit) automatically.

Is there a way to do it?
I cannot find how to remove a text from the middle of the node, only from the start.

Here is the JS code

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';
import * as Lint from 'tslint';
import { IOptions } from 'tslint';

export class Rule extends Lint.Rules.AbstractRule {
  public static FAILURE_STRING = "Something bad happened - you're not 
  following the rules";

  public apply(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile): Lint.RuleFailure[] {
     return this.applyWithWalker(new TestcafeNoOnly(sourceFile, 
        this.getOptions()));
  }
}

// This worker visits every source file
class TestcafeNoOnly extends Lint.RuleWalker {
   private readonly FAILURE_STRING = 'Testcafe no only';
   private readonly PROHIBITED = ['fixture.only', 'test.only'];
   private readonly REGEX = new RegExp('^(' + this.PROHIBITED.join('|') + ')$');

  constructor(sourceFile: ts.SourceFile, options: IOptions) {
     super(sourceFile, options);
  }

  public visitCallExpression(node: ts.CallExpression) {
     const match = 
     node.expression.getText().replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r\t|\s)/gm, '').trim().match(this.REGEX);

    if (match) {
       const fix = Lint.Replacement.deleteText(node.getStart(), 5);
       this.addFailureAt(node.getStart(), match[0].length, this.FAILURE_STRING, fix);
    }

   super.visitCallExpression(node);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This rule already exists in [tslint-microsoft-contrib](https://github.com/microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib) as [`mocha-avoid-only`](https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib/blob/master/src/mochaAvoidOnlyRule.ts). Hooray!

You're calling `node.getStart()` where `node` is a `CallExpression`, so what you're getting is the start of `describe.only(...)`.

- `node.expression` is the `describe`
- `node.name` is the `only`

You want to delete from the end of `node.expression` *(so it includes the `.` even if there's a space there)* to the end of the `node.name`. Something like:

```
Lint.Replacement.deleteFromTo(node.name.end, node.expression.end);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but... the mocha tslint rule won’t help me as I’m looking for different syntax(need fixture and test. Not describe) and I don’t want to delete it from the end since it may chain other function: test.only(“my test”).before().blabla

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to duplicate your current `tslint.json` to (for example) `tslint-no-only.json`.

In `tslint-no-only.json` modify the `rules` section:

```
"rules": {
        ...
        "ban": [
            true,
            "eval",
            {
                "name": ["test", "only"],
                "message": "do not commit with test.only"
            },
            {
                "name": ["fixture", "only"],
                "message": "do not commit with fixture.only"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Just reference this new tslint file inside Husky configuration.

Comment: I didn’t understand why I need to duplicate the tslint when I’m trying to create a new rule to my current one

Comment: @doron, yes you are right, no need to duplicate if you are not using `tsc` as a precheck before starting TestCafe.